# Can my MacBook be repaired under 2 year limited warranty?

Tags: warranty

My M1 MacBook Air packed up just 3 months post-warranty period. I didn’t buy AppleCare+. It’s turning on/off intermittently. The issue with one charging port was present for quite some time but I was not so concerned because it was working after a couple of attempts and didn’t think it would land on such a serious problem. MacBook was bought in the UK but currently, I am abroad outside the EU.

Just wondering, is there any luck in claiming the 2-year limited warranty or under consumer law from Apple? I couldn’t quite figure out what they’re saying here, can someone help me decode the language, please?

[Apple Two (2) Year Limited Warranty
(UK and Ireland)](https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/warranty/products/uk-ireland-warranty-edition.html)

Comment: A couple of things…until you attempt a claim with Apple, you’ll have exactly a 0% chance of success.  We can speak on behalf of Apple; each customer’s experience is different.  Secondly, we can’t break down legal jargon on such a broad scope.  Is there a specific question/section you can focus on?

Comment: Really the only one who can answer that, authoritatively, is *Apple themselves.* I have on occasion gotten an Apple support rep to bend the warranty a bit in my favor. I find that being really nice, kind, understanding and apologetic works wonders. So (leaving the law out of it) it is **possible** that you could get it repaired under warranty, with a little luck...

Comment: Contact Apple, they will decide the outcome. Done so twice and looked after both times.

Comment: Whilst Apple may bend the warranty time frame (and repair it under warranty), you do need to understand your consumer law rights and be ready to ask for repair under UK consumer law. You may have trouble getting a repair under UK consumer law unless you present the Mac to Apple UK.

Comment: This is worth reading: https://www.apple.com/uk/legal/statutory-warranty/uk/